# installed a new version of iTunes, 12.0.1.26 - albuns not colsolidated

Tags: itunes

I just installed a new version of iTunes, 12.0.1.26. When I want to add a new music album into my music  it is Displaying as individual songs in Music Library. Kindly Find the Image Attached. FYI[image]

Answer (score 1):

Select a song from the album, then press Command+I to view/edit the song's metadata.

There is a field in there called "Album Artist". Edit all the songs so that they have the same album artist and they will show up as one album.